# Linux user scheme for a Django production server

Tags: python, django, linux, nginx, uwsgi

I'm currently trying to set up nginx + uWSGI server for my Django homepage. Some tutorials advice me to create specific UNIX users for certain daemons. Like *nginx* user for nginx daemon and so on. As I'm new to Linux administration, I thought just to create second user for running all the processes (nginx, uWSGI etc.), but it turned out that I need some `--system` users for that.

Main question is what users would you set up for nginx + uWSGI server and how to work with them? Say, I have server with freshly installed Debian Squeeze.

Should I install all the packages, virtual environment and set up all the directories as root user and then create system ones to run the scripts?

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with Debian-provided packages as much as you can, unless there are specific features in newer versions that you need. The packages will handle user creation for you, which is one more reason why they're so nice to use. :)

Comment: Yes, it does, but I think I should not run my own scripts under root, right? You mean, it is okay to have only root user and system ones? Is it okay for security?

Comment: @Alexander, it depends what the script should do :) you're absolutely right that your web site shouldn't run as root. Hopefully the Debian nginx package creates an nginx account and configures it to change to that user at startup...

Comment: @sarnold i'll repeat previous edit just to clarify: is it okay to have only root user and system ones? I don't need any regular users then?

Comment: @Alex, aha :) I like having regular users on a system: (a) multiple admins show up in `sudo` logs (b) not all tasks require admin privileges, but admin-level mistakes can be more costly to repair. But you're right, you can do all your work as `root` and not bother with regular user accounts.

Comment: thanks in advance, would you make some proper answer? I will wait few days and accept, if it is best. Comments are not for answers, I suppose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like having regular users on a system:

- multiple admins show up in sudo logs -- there's nothing quite like asking a specific person *why* they made a specific change.
- not all tasks require admin privileges, but admin-level mistakes can be more costly to repair
- it is easier to manage the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if each file contains only keys from a specific user -- if you get four or five different users in the file, it's harder to manage. Small point :) but it is so easy to write `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remotehost "cat - > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` -- if one must use `>>` instead, it's precarious. :)

But you're right, you can do all your work as root and not bother with regular user accounts.

Comment: He is asking regarding the user accounts under which the separate processes run (nginx, uwsgi), not regarding the administrator's account

Comment: @yeeeev: I think he was asking a different question; see [this clarifying comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986472/linux-user-scheme-for-a-django-production-server/5986912#comment6911609_5986472), _is it okay to have only root user and system ones? I don't need any regular users then?_